# Oracle Apex Derive Status based on dates

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an interactive grid with the following columns:

```
select emp_id,active,start_date,end_date from emp;

Active
Start Date
End Date
```

If End Date < Current Date, the Status column should display Inactive else active.
Status is a Display only column and would just display Active/Inactive based on the condition.

How and where can i add this validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a validation, but another column in interactive grid's query; `case` expression is simple enough:

```
select emp_id, active, start_date, end_date,
  --
  case when end_date < sysdate then 'Inactive'
       else 'Active'
  end status
from emp
```

Then navigate to `status` column and turn its "Query only" property ON because it isn't based on database column and you don't want Apex to try to submit it along with other columns.